# Tableau dashboard filter action excluding date but including clients represented in date clicked

Tags: tableau-api

I have a bar chart below that shows the sum of clients by month. I want to be able to click on a month and use a dashboard action to navigate to all data for each of the clients represented in the month that was clicked. Basically, I want to exclude the date portion of the filtering.

I currently do this by navigating to a sheet that includes client_id and filters for the single month and then I select all client_ids and action to another sheet that filters by the selected client_ids and not date. I want to remove the middle step.

[image: sum of clients by month]

If the above selected month is April 2020 and represented 64 clients, my current action takes me to a sheet that has each client on a row and shows me their sum of invoices for April 2020. I want to see those same 64 clients for all months they have transactions in.

Answer (score 0):

This one may be tough to accomplish, but I definitely see what you're setting out to do. If you're using a date dimension on your action it will use that data to filter.

However, there may be some other options depending on what you're needing. If don't need to see the invoice ids and only want to see the sum of invoices for all months you could use a LOD (Level of Detail) calculated field.

You would create a calculated field like:
{ FIXED [client_id] : SUM([your invoice amount measure])}

Use this as a new column to get the sum of all invoices in your data set for each client.